# Handling file paths in cmd in java

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I am trying to copy a file from a folder and paste in another folder through command line with my java program but I am getting a bunch of different errors. My code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String src = args[0];
    String dest = args[1];
    String temp[] = src.split("\\");
    String fileName = temp[temp.length-1];
    String data;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    try
    {
        fr = new FileReader(src);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        fw = new FileWriter(dest + "\\" + fileName);
        pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        data = br.readLine();
        while(data != null)
        {
            pw.println(data);
            data = br.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong with my code. Thanks in advance.

These are the error I am getting on cmd
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSS8n.jpg

Comment: "I am getting a bunch of errors" - what errors?  Please edit your question to include the errors you are getting.

Comment: Use the `File` API to manipulate paths. Or, better yet, the `Path` API.

Comment: Are you running multiple versions of Java on your machine?

Comment: Going by the error, it looks like your JDK and JRE versions are different. The code was compiled using JDK but another version of JRE is trying to run the code.

Comment: That error has nothing to do with your code, but rather with your compilation. You compiled with a JDK11 compiler and are trying to run with a JDK8 (or JRE8) runtime, which doesn't work. If you have more than one version of Java installed on your machine (possibly including one installed as part of your IDE, if you are using an IDE, which you didn't say) check your PATH to see which one will be run from CMD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Paths instead for getting de path:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String src = args[0];
    String dest = args[1];

    String fileName = Paths.get(src).getFileName().toString();

    System.out.println("fileName:" + fileName);

    String data;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(src);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        fw = new FileWriter(dest + "\\" + fileName);
        pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        data = br.readLine();
        while (data != null) {
            pw.println(data);
            data = br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I tried this in Eclipse, and with a Jar, and works fine:

[image]

Comment: This works fine for filename but the path stored in string is as "C:abc\xyz\aaa.txt" whereas it should be as "C:abc\\xyz\\aaa.txt" for it to work. I am pretty sure that is the reason for errors I am getting. I have also attached an image of errors to help others understand my problem. Thank you

Comment: @Jerry555555: the actual path should have single backslash, and should have one just after the drive (C:\whatever). In string and character literals _in Java source_ the backslash must be doubled, but on the command line in Windows and other runtime input and output it is not. If you are using a debugger it _may_ be doubled there depending on the debugger. (Unix shells require doubling backslash in _some_ places but not others, but that's more complicated plus you wouldn't be using Windows paths on Unix anyway.)

Comment: @Jerry555555 you don't have any backslash or whatsoever in the cmd picture. I edited my answer with a test.